# set idx foward and backward column based in start point within group

Tags: r, dataframe, count, tidyverse

I have a question about something I'm trying deal with.

Imagine I have a data frame like this:

```
| index | item | group | reference |  
|-------|------|-------|-----------|  
| 1     | a    | 0     | 0         |  
| 2     | b    | 0     | 0         |  
| 3     | c    | 0     | 1         |  
| 4     | d    | 0     | 0         |  
| 5     | e    | 0     | 0         |  
| 6     | f    | 1     | 0         |  
| 7     | g    | 1     | 0         |  
| 8     | h    | 1     | 1         |  
| 9     | i    | 1     | 0         |  
| 10    | j    | 1     | 0         |  
|-------|------|-------|-----------|
```

I'd like, based in `reference == 1`, numbering lines within each group `group_by(., group)` start the offset in reference and increment to below and decrement to above.
In the end I should have something like this:

```
| index | item | group | reference | gidx |   
|-------|------|-------|-----------|------|  
| 1     | a    | 0     | 0         | -2   |
| 2     | b    | 0     | 0         | -1   |  
| 3     | c    | 0     | 1         | 0    |
| 4     | d    | 0     | 0         | 1    |
| 5     | e    | 0     | 0         | 2    |  
| 6     | f    | 1     | 0         | -2   |  
| 7     | g    | 1     | 0         | -1   |  
| 8     | h    | 1     | 1         | 0    |  
| 9     | i    | 1     | 0         | 1    |  
| 10    | j    | 1     | 0         | 2    |  
|-------|------|-------|-----------|------|
```

Does anybody knows how to deal with this.
Better using dplyr or tidyverse.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After grouping by 'group', we can subtract the row_number from the index where the 'reference' is 1 (assuming there is only a single 1 value in 'reference' for each 'group')

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(gidx = row_number() - which(reference == 1))
   # or use which.max`
   # mutate(gidx = row_number() - which.max(reference))    
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   group [2]
#   index item  group reference  gidx
#   <int> <chr> <int>     <int> <int>
# 1     1 a         0         0    -2
# 2     2 b         0         0    -1
# 3     3 c         0         1     0
# 4     4 d         0         0     1
# 5     5 e         0         0     2
# 6     6 f         1         0    -2
# 7     7 g         1         0    -1
# 8     8 h         1         1     0
# 9     9 i         1         0     1
#10    10 j         1         0     2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(index = 1:10, item = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 
 "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), group = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L), reference = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
  0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```